# Function with svm binaries

Tags: matlab, function, svm

I work on Image Quality Assessment Algortihms. My problem is the following: When I call a function that needs two binaries (.Exe) files (needed for SVM classification) that is not in the current folder (after changing the path, including adding sub paths) so that it provides a result A. When I put it in the folder where the function is, so that it provides a result B (which the correct result). I do not understand why this metric provides two different results? What I realized is that when I call the function to its own directory, so that it recognizes the EXE files which I have spoken. however when I call out the current directory, it do not know the .EXE !!

i notice that if you are in the folder that contains all the functions of the metric, it gives a result.

and if you are out the file, and although you add the path and subpath of the folder containing the codes, so after test, you will have a second income.

I'm waiting for your response.

Thank you.

---

I tested the code containing the binaries separately (so 2 disctincts binaries from any other DLL), but again, it works differently when I'm in the back and when I'm out. When I'm in the folder, the program recognizes (svm-predict, and svm-scale) commands. and when I'm out, the program does not recognize them and provided a different result.

I think the problem is here?

I put the code in this link (http://www.4shared.com/zip/IrOOsChj/BIQI_release.html) you can download it and test it.
To test just load an image, and to call the function: score_quality=biqi(img) (In the read me that came with the code, the author says that it is not obligaoire have previously installed the libsvm).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A theory:  The exe files you are using are relying on one or more DLLs (or other linked code) for which you have multiple versions in your path.  For example, A.exe need G.dll.  G.dll is in two places in your path.  When you invoke A.exe from different locations, it uses different linked code.

This could also happen if you have multiple versions of A.exe and have too many directories in your path.  If you happen to be in the home directory for A.exe, it uses that A.exe.  When you are in another directory, and type A.exe, you might be calling some other A.exe.

I recommend renaming your your two binaries something very specific:  foo1.exe and bar1.exe.  Use these names in your function.  If your function doesn't find these then ***move*** the files around until they are in the correct location. Do not make copies!

Good luck.